# WordPress doesn't respect nginx headers

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, header

I host some websites on my VPS, some "static" and some dynamic (WordPress). The static websites (static PHP pages) "respect" the headers I set in nginx conf, http section. Example:

```
add_header  Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
add_header  X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
```

Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 16 Sep 2014 17:09:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Cache: HIT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;
```

WordPress websites instead don't have these headers I set:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 16 Sep 2014 17:08:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Pingback: http://website.com/xmlrpc.php
Link: <http://wp.me/P4zIfv-2>; rel=shortlink
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

The two websites have the same vhost config! Of course liste, server_name, index ecc.. and then the locations:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_cache website.com;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 20m;    
    fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
    fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;

    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;           
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Why does this happen with WP?

Answer (score 1):

See: [nginx add_header not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450310/nginx-add-header-not-working)

"Second issue was that the location / {} block I had in place was actually sending nginx to the other location ~* (.php)$ block (because it would repath all requests through index.php, and that actually makes nginx process this php block). So, my add_header directives inside the first location directive were useless, and it started working after I put all the directives I needed inside the php location directive."

See also: https://gist.github.com/adityamenon/6753574

So put them INSIDE your location block

Comment: I already read that but it doesn't make much sense. The add_header directives are in the "general" http section. Not server section. Shouldn't they be applied to EVERY location?

Comment: Nginx directives are inherited from higher order sections. So directives placed in the `http` are inherited by all servers and locations unless overridden while those placed in a `server`section are inherited by all location blocks under it unless overriden.