# Websockets with NGINX and Rails ActionCable

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, websocket, actioncable

What is wrong with our configuration?  NGINX is not adding the proper headers.

Using React front end to initialize client with `wss` connection, received by AWS ELB, passed unencrypted to nginx, proxy_passed to Rails backend.

React connection url
`wss://mydomain.com/ws/cable`

nginx config
`location /ws/ {
    proxy_pass ​http://backend_host/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
}`

In Rails, the ws fails [here](https://github.com/faye/websocket-driver-ruby/blob/b14488aac51b7e3be726c74ecc7fcd8cb14819e3/lib/websocket/driver.rb#L223-L230) because `env['HTTP_CONNECTION']` and `env['HTTP_UPGRADE']` are not correctly set by nginx.

`env['HTTP_CONNECTION']` should equal "Upgrade" and instead is "close"
`env['HTTP_UPGRADE']` should equal "websocket" and instead is nil

What can we change in nginx to fix these headers?

Comment: Try removing the http:// before backend_host, so you just have `proxy_pass backend_host`.

Comment: ELB basically does not support Websockets with HTTP/HTTPS listeners. Consider moving to TCP listeners with proxy protocol support or migrate to ALB ("ELBv2"), which is officially able to handle WS connections.

Comment: Did you check this ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450310/nginx-add-header-not-working